# InnerHTML tag not working in my JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript, html

Please help it works on one desktop and not another.  I am getting an error in my JavaScript 'Unable to get property'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference.

**Code:**

```
function add_fields(e) {
  var docs = document.getElementsByClassName("doc");
  var revs = document.getElementsByClassName("rev");

  idx = docs.length;

  var saveDocs = new Array(idx);
  var saveRevs = new Array(idx);

  for (n = 0; n < idx; n++) {
    saveDocs[n] = docs[n].value;
    saveRevs[n] = revs[n].value;
  }

  node = document.getElementById("content");
  theNewRow = document.createElement("tr");

  theNewCell = theNewRow.insertCell(0);

  theNewCell.innerHTML = "Approver Name"; //Error on this line
  theNewCell.setAttribute("style", "font-size: 12pt");

  theNewCell1 = theNewRow.insertCell(1);
  theNewCell1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='doc' style='width:180px;' id='docNum0'/>";
  theNewCell1.setAttribute("style", "padding-left: 10px");

  theNewCell2 = theNewRow.insertCell(2);
  theNewCell2.innerHTML = "Approver Email";
  theNewCell2.setAttribute("style", "font-size: 12pt");
  theNewCell2.setAttribute("style", "padding-left: 10px");

  theNewCell3 = theNewRow.insertCell(3);
  theNewCell3.innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='rev' style='width:180px;' id='rev0'/>  <input class='minusThing' type='button' style='font-size:10px' value='- '/>";
  theNewCell3.setAttribute("style", "padding-left: 0px");

  node.appendChild(theNewRow);
```

Comment: This is actually an interesting question, because `theNewCell` is defined just above the error. Though the error is probably "_Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference_".

Comment: You are correct my apologize the error is actually 'Unable to set property innerHTML of undefined or null reference'.. I have not had coffee yet.

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831712/insertrow-returns-null-in-ie7

Comment: Well ... now you'll need more coffee, because your code works as it is = ), it doesn't fire an error on that line. See it [at jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0o1azkw/). I've just emulated the core of the question, there's not all the code in the fiddle.

Comment: Hmm, can't reproduce locally. Creating a `tr` programatically, calling `insertCell(0)` on it one or even multiple times always produces a `td`. Any more information here? Where are you running this, for example? Anything that will lead to a [mcve]?

Comment: I am running the code on a desktop with no internet connectivity

Comment: In which browser? Double-check the spelling of the variable names, if there's no code between those two lines, the said error is impossible without a typo in the var name.

Comment: Also the note the src file for js is being pulled locally instead over the net

Comment: The browser is IE=10
here is the header:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<HTA:APPLICATION
     APPLICATIONNAME="tool"
  />

Comment: I run the code in a hta, no errors occurred ..?

Comment: Here is the HTML section if it helps
'''
<table  border="0"  id="content"  >
  <tr>
   <td style="font-size: 12pt">Approver Name:</td> 
   <td style="padding-left: 10px" style="font-size: 12pt" id="doccontainer"><input type="text" class="doc" name="doc number" style="width:180px;" id="docNum0"/></td>
 
   <td style="padding-left: 10px" style="font-size: 12pt" >Approver Email: </td>
   <td><input type="text" class="rev" name="rev" style="width:180px;" id="rev0"> <input class="plusThing" type="button" style="font-size: 10px" id="more_fields"  value="+"/></td>
  </tr>
 </table>'

Comment: Thank you Teemu, if no errors are occuring then it something to do with the desktop i am using

Comment: Everything copied as you've provided here, but no errors, not a single error, clicking `+` button adds a new row just as expected.

Comment: Thank you Teemu, I need to troubleshoot this machine. Thank you

Comment: Maybe you should copy the code from the post here, and test with it first ..? Just remember to add the missing `}` at the end of the function.

Comment: Thank you Teemu, i figured it out the id=content was missing in the HTML tag.